# Filter data results for current month only and find sum AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display the sum of a property of my data `(entry.payout)` for entries from the current month only, and after looking at a bunch of filters and functions, frankly I'm baffled.

```
<div class="monthly-earnings">
  <p>Earnings This Month</p>
  <p>{{ getMonthlyEarnings(month) }} </p>
</div>
```

My Angular controller data get request

```
$http.get('/api/user').then(function(response){
    $scope.entries = response.data;

  $scope.getMonthlyEarnings = function(month){
    var monthlyEarnings = 0;
    var filterBy = $filter('filterBy');

    // this is where only current month's entries should be filtered
    $scope.selectedMonth = function(month){
      $scope.entries = filterBy($scope.entries, month);
    }   

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedMonth.length; i++){
      var entry = $scope.selectedMonth[i];
      monthlyEarnings += (entry.payout);
    }
    return monthlyEarnings.toFixed(2);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is the `filterBy` filter defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AngularJS built in filter to filter the response by month. 
You should be getting the filter named `filter`. You can use this to filter your response to filter by property.

For example, you can get the `filter` and filter a list using the month property.

```
var filter = filterBy = $filter('filter'); //Getting the filter

//Filter only results with a month property of 'JAN'
$scope.filteredSalaryArray = filter($scope.salaryArray, {month: 'JAN'})
```

Now you can use the filtered array to do your calculations.

I've created a JSFiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3594/

Comment: This works if you have a specific month you're talking about (i.e. 'JAN'), but I need to filter it to only the current month's data, whatever month it is. I'll select this as the correct answer this if you can help with that. My data has a timestamp property `createdAt` if that helps.

Comment: That is simply a matter of replacing `JAN` with a variable which contains the month text. In what format do you get the month?

Comment: A timestamp property `createdAt`, which gives the date in the long format.

Comment: @PanicBus http://jsfiddle.net/nipuna777/Lvc0u55v/3600/ This is one way of how you could filter by this month. There are of course many other ways.

Comment: This part of your fiddle helped a ton: `filter($scope.salaryArray, {month: thisMonth})`: I changed `month` to `createdAt` and was able to filter out the dates from the DB correctly. Thanks!